# Validator for ant design form.list

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying write a Form.List validator to check for duplicate values (name), the code works as expected if I fill the field at the first index first then create a new index (new rows of field), then fill the fields at the second index, and so on... but if I create two or more rows(index) at the same time and try to fill the second index at first (leaving the first blank), it gives an error. See the rules I wrote

I have been trying this whole day to get the value of list when typing on the name field and if any object is null return desired error message but with no luck.

Any help to deal with validators?

```
        <Form.List name="ABC">
          {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
            <>
              {fields.map(
                ({ key, name, fieldKey, ...restField }) => (
                          <Form.Item
                            label={`Series Name ${
                              fieldKey + 1
                            }`}
                            {...restField}
                            name={[name, "name"]}
                            fieldKey={[fieldKey, "name"]}
                            rules={[
                              {
                                required: true,
                                // whitespace: true,
                                message: "Missing series name",
                              },
                              ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
                                validator(_, value) {
                                  if (
                                    !value ||
                                    getFieldValue("ABC")
                                    .filter(
                                      (d) => d.name === value
                                    ).length === 1
                                  ) {
                                    return Promise.resolve();
                                  }
                                  return Promise.reject(
                                    new Error(
                                      "Duplicate values are not allowed."
                                    )
                                  );
                                },
                              }),
                            ]}
                          >
                            <Input placeholder="Series Name" />
                          </Form.Item>
                        </Col>



                      <Form.Item>
                        <MinusCircleOutlined
                          onClick={() => {
                            remove(name);
                          }}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                )
              )}

              <Form.Item {...button}>
                  <Button
                  type="primary"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
               >
                  Create Series
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </>
          )}
        </Form.List>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create two new rows and fill the second row, in filter you check for `d.name` === to that value. Since you haven't enter any value in first row or field, `name` is currently undefined in `ABC` array.

[image]

`d.name` doesn't exist yet that's why it gives you error.

If you do not touch the field, it will remain undefined. Once you type into that field, it will add `{ name: somevalue }`

Solution:
Just add Optional Chain Operator `?` in `d?.name === value`.

Hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: I got your point, but this way there will be no error message that some fields are blank, you need to fill those or remove them. also once you type on the second field and then delete all the text it gives you some type of error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally wrote the validator, hope this helps someone.(will improve this)

```
        rules={[
          ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
            validator(_, value) {
              if (
                !value ||
                getFieldValue(
                  selectedFormType
                ).some(
                  (d) => d === undefined
                )
              ) {
                return Promise.reject(
                  new Error(
                    "Few name fields are blank, remove them."
                  )
                );
              } else if (
                !value ||
                getFieldValue(
                  selectedFormType
                ).filter(
                  (d) => d.name === value
                ).length !== 1
              ) {
                return Promise.reject(
                  new Error(
                    "Duplicate values are not allowed."
                  )
                );
              } else {
                return Promise.resolve();
              }
            },
          }),
        ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code there is several issue like it's show error last index only and if no return will all field show error with index.

here is full fix and tested

```
rules={[({getFieldValue}) => ({
         validator(_, value) {
                 return validateField(getFieldValue, value, 'value')
   }})]}



function validateField(getFieldValue, value, key) {
    let fieldValue = getFieldValue('seerportal_parameters');
    if (!value) {
        for (let i = 0; i < fieldValue.length; i++) {
            let j = fieldValue[i];
            if (j === undefined) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error(`Please enter parameter ${key}!`));
            }
        }
    } else {
        let filtered = fieldValue.filter((d) => (d && d[key]) === value);
        if (filtered.length !== 1) {
            for (let i = 0; i < fieldValue.length; i++) {
                let j = fieldValue[i];
                if (j) {

                    if (filtered[0][key] === j[key]) {
                        return Promise.reject(new Error(`Duplicate parameter ${key} found`));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }
}
```